# TypeScript proxy generation with nSwag: Null checks on nullable int

Tags: c#, typescript, nswag

We are using a .net core WebAPI backend and use nSwag to generate TypeScript proxies to be used in the frontend. This is the backend/C# code:

```
public class MyDto
{
    public MyDto() { }   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? OtherObject { get; set; }
}
```

and the controller method

```
    [Route("SaveEditedDto")]
    [HttpPost]
    public EditResultDto SaveEditedDto(MyDto dto)
```

The generated TypeScript for the "save" method looks like this:

```
saveEditedDto(id: number | undefined, otherObject: number | undefined): Observable<EditResultDto> {
    let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/MyDomain/SaveEditedDto?";
    if (oid === null)
        throw new Error("The parameter 'oid' cannot be null.");
    else if (oid !== undefined)
        url_ += "Oid=" + encodeURIComponent("" + oid) + "&";
    if (otherObject === null)
        throw new Error("The parameter 'otherObject' cannot be null.");
    else if (otherObject !== undefined)
        url_ += "OtherObject=" + encodeURIComponent("" + otherObject) + "&";
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");
```

I have actually two questions about this:

1. Why is the a null check on the *OtherObject* parameter? It doesn't make any sense to me, because the field in the DTO is nullable.
2. More important: **How do I get nSwag not to put the null check in?**

Answer (score 1):

I believe, what you want to achieve is not get rid of the null check itself, but dodge it. Looks like nswag generated code to me. It is clearly depicted here:

```
else if (oid !== undefined)
        url_ += "Oid=" + encodeURIComponent("" + oid) + "&";
```

...

```
else if (otherObject !== undefined)else if (otherObject !== undefined)
        url_ += "OtherObject=" + encodeURIComponent("" + otherObject) + "&";
```

that all you might need to do is pass undefined rather than null as parameters `oid` and `otherObject`.

This hint is given by the creator himself, as well here:
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1067