# Nswag adds null check for nullable/optional parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openapi, nswag

I have basically same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63741091/typescript-proxy-generation-with-nswag-null-checks-on-nullable-int) ([details here on Github](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1067)) but with C# client - `[FromForm] SomeObject x` on controller has some nullable (optional) parameters and generated client generated by Nswag has null checks in place like this:

```
public virtual async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Attachment> UploadAsync(int? idProject = null, int? idTicket = null...
...
if (idProject == null) throw new System.ArgumentNullException("idProject");
else
{
    content_.Add(new System.Net.Http.StringContent(ConvertToString(idProject, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), "IdProject");
}
...
```

Both original model (from API project) and generated one in client project have those fields as nullable and function call accepts nullable values.

JSON schema from swagger looks like this:

```
"/Attachment/Upload": {
  "post": {
    "tags": [
      "Attachment"
    ],
    "requestBody": {
      "content": {
        "multipart/form-data": {
          "schema": {
            "required": [
              "Name"
            ],
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "IdProject": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32"
              },
              "IdTicket": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32"
              },...
```

I've tried setting `"queryNullValue": ""` in `openApiToCSharpClient` but it does not help. How to disable those checks in generated client? I must use `[FromForm]` since I'm sending both file(s) and some additional data with them.

Nswag file (generator settings only):

```
"openApiToCSharpClient": {
  "generateClientInterfaces": true,
  "GenerateClientClasses": true,
  "useBaseUrl": false,
  "namespace": "xxxxxxxx.APIClient",
  "className": "{controller}Client",
  "operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromFirstTagAndOperationName",
  "jsonLibrary": "SystemTextJson",
  "generateDtoTypes": true,
  "disposeHttpClient": true,
  "injectHttpClient": true,
  "httpClientType": "System.Net.Http.HttpClient",
  "UseHttpRequestMessageCreationMethod": false,
  "generateBaseUrlProperty": false,
  "generateOptionalParameters": true,
  "parameterArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList",
  "responseArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList",
  "generateOptionalPropertiesAsNullable": true,
  "generateNullableReferenceTypes": true,
  "output": "Client.g.cs",
  "generateExceptionClasses": true,
  "dateType": "System.DateTime",
  "dateTimeType": "System.DateTime",
  "queryNullValue": "",
  "additionalNamespaceUsages": [
    "global::APIClient"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing nullable in .json schema:

But .NET dont default adds nullable (it probably bug).
I found solution for swaggergen, maybe it will help you.
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2157

They write own OperationFilter that finds all 'form-data' attributes and all of them, that are not required, makes optional.

```
public class SwaggerOptionalFormDataFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.RequestBody?.Content.ContainsKey("multipart/form-data") ?? false)
        {
            foreach (var content in operation.RequestBody.Content)
            {
                var requiredProps = content.Value.Schema.Required;
                var props = content.Value.Schema.Properties;
                foreach (var prop in props)
                {
                    var paramterDescription = context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.FirstOrDefault(paramDesc => paramDesc.Name == prop.Key);
                    if (!requiredProps.Contains(prop.Key) && paramterDescription != null && paramterDescription.Type.IsReferenceOrNullableType())
                    {
                        prop.Value.Nullable = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34109925)